# Strange table update codeigniter $this->db->update

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with an update of one table in the db. I always use the same approach and I have no problem. Although in this case I have an issue...

The code:

**the view:**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Modifica Dati Check-in Cliente</legend>

    <?php 
                $passeggeri='placeholder="Passeggeri"';
                $animali='placeholder="Animali"';
                $note='placeholder="Note"';

        echo form_open('site/esegui_modifica_record_check_in');
                    echo form_hidden('id',$id[0]->id);
                    echo form_hidden('rif_parcheggio',$id[0]->rif_parcheggio);
        echo form_input('Passeggeri',set_value('passeggeri',$id[0]->passeggeri),$passeggeri);
        echo form_input('Animali',set_value('animali',$id[0]->animali),$animali);
        echo form_input('Note',set_value('note',$id[0]->note),$note);
                    ?> <br/> <input type="datetime-local" name="data_in_inserita" value="<?php echo strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', strtotime($id[0]->data_in));?>" /> <?php
                    echo form_submit('submit','Modifica');
                    echo form_close();

?>
</fieldset>
```

**controller:**

```
function esegui_modifica_record_check_in() {
 $this->load->model('membership_model');
 if($query = $this->membership_model->esegui_modifica_record_check_in())
 {
      $this->load->view('check_in_auto_succesful');
 }
 else 
 {
     $this->load->view('admin');
 }
}
```

**model:**

```
function esegui_modifica_record_check_in() {
        $update_record_check2= array (
            'passeggeri' => $this->input->post('passeggeri'),
            'animali' => $this->input->post('animali'),
            'note' => $this->input->post('note'),
            'data_in' => $this->input->post('data_in_inserita')
        );  

        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $insert = $this->db->update('check2', $update_record_check2);
        return $insert; 
    }
```

The query is executed but the values are updates as zero (0) character for the modified fields.

It's very strange! this is my first problem with the update function of codeigniter

I don't have a clear idea. Could you please help me?
thanks a lot

by

Comment: _but the DB is update with all 0 (zero) charachter for the modify fields_ what does this mean? could you paraphrase it? does it actually execute the update but the values are updates as zero `(0)`? or the `affected_rows` is equal to zero?

Comment: @Ghost the values are updates as zero (0) ...sorry for the english im italian

Comment: no worries, i'm also atrocious at english. one way to debug is to check `$this->input->post()` values first, before you pass them inside your model methods

Comment: @Ghost can you give me an example ?

Comment: just use `var_dump($this->input->post())` inside the controller, then if you know its not empty, then use it next inside the model, step by step, check if your values are really in there

Comment: incredible @Ghost only " $this->input->post('data_in_inserita') " and 
" $this->input->post('id') " are posted

Comment: yeah, thats the reason why, some fields are empty, my suggestion is why not just use a normal html form and just echo those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to debug is to make sure that values are really being passed into your model method. Either debug first on the controller or inside you model:

Controller:

```
function esegui_modifica_record_check_in() 
{
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    // rest of codes
}
```

OR

Model:

```
function esegui_modifica_record_check_in() 
{
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    // rest of codes
}
```

Then, assuming you haven't fixed it yet. You have a case mismatch on the input `name=""`

```
echo form_input('Passeggeri',set_value('passeggeri',$id[0]->passeggeri),$passeggeri);
'passeggeri' => $this->input->post('passeggeri'),
// Passeggeri !== passeggeri

echo form_input('Animali',set_value('animali',$id[0]->animali),$animali);
'animali' => $this->input->post('animali'),
// Animali !== animali

echo form_input('Note',set_value('note',$id[0]->note),$note);
'note' => $this->input->post('note'),
// Animali !== animali
```

You should take that also into account. You need to follow the same case letters. Make them the **same**

Either:

```
echo form_input('Passeggeri',
$this->input->post('Passeggeri')
```

Or

```
echo form_input('passeggeri',
$this->input->post('passeggeri')
```

Sidenote:

As my suggestion above, I would just make it simple and use a normal form.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('site/esegui_modifica_record_check_in'); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="passeggeri" value="<?php echo $id[0]->passeggeri; ?>" placeholder="Passeggeri" />
    <!-- and other text box inputs -->
</form>
```

Comment: @riccardoairone yeah, thats what i would have done in the first place, much straightforward that way